# Security risk in showing user salted/hashed password?

Tags: security, sha512

I have an password that is salted and then encrypted with sha512. Is there any security concern if the user can see the salted/encrypted hash string (for example, in a URL parameter)?

Comment: What would be the scenario where hashed password would be in a URL parameter?

Comment: It's a weird website set up, complicated to explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Providing a hashed password, even salted is IMHO a clear conflict with good security practice, especially if the hash is used in an URL.

Keep in mind that the browser cache saves all URLs visited, therefore an attacker could use the browser cache to extract the password hash and then start to break it, e.g. by using one of the common password lists.

Therefore I would never use a simple salted and hashed password as a parameter in an URL.

The only way I would I would accept a password hash is if the used hash is an HMAC (e.g. HMAC SHA-512) with a user specific random key that never leaves the server. In this case the password hash would usually be useless to an attacker.